# Collisions of very high velocity objects that have a relative small velocity difference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

Suppose that two objects are in space (i.e. vacuum). One is travelling at some very high velocity, say $14.000 km/h$ and the second is travelling at $14.010 km/h$, so it is a $10 km/h$ difference in velocity between them.

If they collide, in what way would the properties of the collision be different from if two objects travelling at $10 km/h$ and $20 km/h$ collide (i.e. smaller velocities, same velocity difference, both also in space)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In space, there is no difference. The only thing that matters is the relative velocity of the 2 objects. At the extreme, if the relative velocity were 0, they would just stay in (or out of) contact with each other forever.

Think of the astronauts in the ISS. They are floating around in the spacecraft. If they push off against the wall, they might pick up a relative velocity of 10 km/h with the ISS, but they will still only hit the opposite wall at 10 km/h.

On earth it would be different, as at 14000 km/h the objects would vaporise due to atmospheric friction before they had a chance to get into contact.

Comment: Ok! The question originated from my curiosity as to why tiny debris in space causes disproportionately large dents/damage on spacecraft. I guess it is because the relative velocity is very large then?

Comment: High relative velocity is indeed what's doing the damage. Even if satellites are in similar orbits, the relative velocity can still be a few km/s, more than the speed of a bullet.